# Environment variables are not recognized by Laravel in Docker

Tags: docker, laravel-5, environment-variables, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm having trouble working with environment variables in Docker.

For some reason Laravel can't see the environment variables I set within Dockerfile. Like APP_KEY, APP_ENV, etc. But when I SSH into the docker container:

```
docker exec -it [container_name] bash
```

and run the following:

```
php artisan tinker
> print_r($_ENV)
```

The environment variable exists and is set to the proper value. However, when I tried to do the same within the Blade template, I don't see the APP_KEY, APP_ENV variables at all. I've edited the `php.ini` file in the Docker container so that it shows

```
variables_order = 'EGPCS'
```

Is `.env` file the only way I can pass environment variables into Laravel?

I appreciate all your help.

Cheers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved it! Actually a friend of mine gave me the clue.

Turns out it is the FPM configuration that is removing the environment variables set by Elastic Beanstalk.

Based on this document: http://php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.configuration.php

```
clear_env boolean
```

Clear environment in FPM workers. Prevents arbitrary environmentvariables from reaching FPM worker processes by clearing the environment in workers before env vars specified in this pool configuration are added. Since PHP 5.4.27, 5.5.11, and 5.6.0. Default value: Yes.

So in your `php-fpm.conf` file look for that variable and set it as follows:

```
clear_env = no
```

And you're are good to go! Your Laravel application can then pull the environment variables set in Elastic Beanstalk by using `env()`

I hope that helps someone. Cheers!

Comment: this helped me on my laravel project when using fpm. I was able to get the environment variable using tinker but in the controller, they would also return null until I set this to no. Thanks. spent 7 hours looking for this.

Comment: Lifesaver. I don't know if I actually would have *ever* found this through looking myself. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Using EB CLI instead of `.env`, you can pass environment variables to your docker container in Elastic Beanstalk.

For example:

```
$ eb setenv APP_KEY=xxx APP_ENV=xxx
```

Please read the following documentation:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-setenv.html